# Terminology for torsion semigroups where the order of elements is uniformly finite

Tags: reference-request, terminology, semigroups-and-monoids

A (multiplicatively written) semigroup $\mathbb A = (A, \cdot)$ with the property that ${\rm ord}_\mathbb{A}(a) := |\{a^n: n \in \mathbf N^+\}| < \infty$ for every $a \in A$ is called a periodic (or torsion) semigroup. But what about the case where there exists $M \in \mathbf N^+$ such that ${\rm ord}_{\mathbb{A}}(a) \le M$ for all $a \in A$? The expression "semigroups of finite exponent" comes to mind, but for some reason it doesn't seem to be so common.

Comment: "Periodic of bounded index" is the term I believe.

Comment: Any (sufficiently strong) evidence in support of your believes?

Comment: Bounded torsion is what I would say

Comment: I was looking forward to your comment, @BenjaminSteinberg, and will probably follow your suggestion, although I'm slightly puzzled by the fact that neither MathSciNet nor Google seem to credit it much, up to few remarkable positive feedbacks (e.g., J. Rhodes has used "Bounded torsion semigroups" in _Infinite Iteration of Matrix Semigroups I. Structure Theorem for Torsion Semigroups_, J. Algebra **98** (Feb 1986), No. 2, 422–451).

Comment: I got this term from Rhodes